# Why isn't the code inside two if statements being executed, even though both of them are true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I'm creating a tic tac toe victory condition, so im checking if the first three cells are equal and if they aren't empty in the first place. But even when i fulfill the conditions the code inside the second "if" is not being executed. Is there something wrong with my code? (r1c1 means first row first column) and so on.

```js
if ($('#r1c1').html() !== "") {
  if (($('#r1c1').html() == $('#r1c2').html()) && ($('#r1c1').html() == $('#r1c3').html())) {
    $("#table").css("display", "none");
    $("#victory").css("display", "You Won");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="victory" style="display:none">
  Congratulations, You Won!
</div>
<table style="display:none" id="table">
  <tr>
    <td id="r1c1" style="text-overflow"></td>
    <td id="r1c2"></td>
    <td id="r1c3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="r2c1"></td>
    <td id="r2c2"></td>
    <td id="r2c3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="r3c1"></td>
    <td id="r3c2"></td>
    <td id="r3c3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is r1ce ? p tag or what ?

Comment: It would appear that they're not both true. I'd suggest you may need to `trim()` the HTML values returned. Also note that `You Won` is not a valid setting for the CSS `display` property

Comment: Use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser to step through that code statement by statement, examining what you get from each call, etc. Clearly if they were the same, `==` would be working.

Comment: Check every value from Browser Console and see if it is same or not.

Comment: the r1c1 is a <td> tag...and yes i checked with the console both if statements and they show up as true after i have filled with X or O the first three cells of the table, but the code below wont be executed nonetheless.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes sry about that CSS display property, it was supposed to be $("#victory").css("display", "");  but it still wont change the fact that nothing happens after i fulfill the condition

Comment: @Dav we need to see your HTML in order to help you

Comment: Probably not the problem, but use `$("#table").hide()` and `$("#victory").show()` instead of manually setting the display property.

Comment: @Dav In future please use the `edit` button on your question to format the code so it's readable. I've done it for you in this case though. How are the `td` elements filled with values?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sry for that was trying to do it with the edit but kept on refusing to be edited (im still new here and its a bit confusing)...the td element is being filled by a function such as $(this).html(x) when a click is used on the td element with x being a variable that takes the value depending on what the player chooses to play as "X" or "O". Id like to note that the fields arent filled with images just a rescaled X and O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your statement is fine, i tested it:https://jsfiddle.net/nyxeen/hqyr7dbv/14/
what does not work is $("#victory").css("display", "You Won"); should be $("#victory").css("display", "block"); or $("#victory").show();

```js
var isx = 'x';



 $("#table td").click(function(){
   $(this).html(isx);
    if(isx=="x")isx="o";
    else isx="x";
    if ($('#r1c1').html() !== "") {
   if (($('#r1c1').html() == $('#r1c2').html()) && ($('#r1c1').html() == $('#r1c3').html())) {
        $("#table").hide();
        $("#victory").show();
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
#table tr td{width:40px;height:40px;border: 1px solid black;background:white;cursor:pointer;};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="victory" style="display:none">
  Congratulations, You Won!
</div> 
<table id="table"> 
  <tr> 
    <td id="r1c1" style="text-overflow"></td>  
    <td id="r1c2"></td>
    <td id="r1c3"></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td id="r2c1"></td>
    <td id="r2c2"></td>
    <td id="r2c3"></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td id="r3c1"></td>
    <td id="r3c2"></td>
    <td id="r3c3"></td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: And just for completion:https://jsfiddle.net/nyxeen/hqyr7dbv/21/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having a rly hard time with this one. thanks again man. cheers